# error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'const QString' and 'QDate')

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qdate

I do have problem with declaring QDate and when I used the declared word(value) in the DB insert function with that related value, its keep on prompting with an error. Please do guide and correct me. I have done my part but still it's giving problem; I don't have idea then :(

My Code:

```
#include "cashregister.h"
#include "ui_cashregister.h"


CashRegister::CashRegister(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::CashRegister)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->dateEdit->setDate(QDate::currentDate());

    ui->groupBox_sales->hide();

    ui->pushButton_finish->hide();

    ui->tableView->hide();

    ui->label_totalAmount->hide();

    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
    qsrand((uint)time.msec());
}

CashRegister::~CashRegister()
{
    delete ui;
}

void CashRegister::on_pushButton_createNewReceipt_clicked()
{
    ui->groupBox_sales->show();

    int bigNo, smallNo;
    bigNo = 100;
    smallNo = 0;

    int randomValue = qrand() % ((bigNo + 1) - smallNo) + smallNo;

    ui->label_receiptNum->setText("AST" + QString::number(randomValue));

    QSqlQueryModel *myModel = new QSqlQueryModel();
    QSqlQuery myqry;
    myqry.prepare("SELECT ItemId FROM Item");
    myqry.exec();
    myModel->setQuery(myqry);
    ui->comboBox_itemID->setModel(myModel);

    myqry.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Receipt (ReceiptId VARCHAR(7) UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, ReceiptDate DATE, ReceiptAmount DOUBLE)" );
    myqry.exec();
    myqry.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sold (ReceiptId VARCHAR(7), ItemId VARCHAR(7), SoldQuantity INTEGER, TotalPrice DOUBLE)" );
    myqry.exec();
}

void CashRegister::on_pushButton_next_clicked()
{
    ui->tableView->show();
    ui->pushButton_finish->show();
    ui->label_totalAmount->show();

    QString receiptNo = ui->label_receiptNum->text();
    QString itemSelect = ui->comboBox_itemID->currentText();
    QString qtySold = ui->lineEdit_qtySold->text();
    QDate currentDate = QDate::currentDate();   //<--THIS-->//
    QString totalAmount = ui->label_totalAmount->text();


    double price=0, totalPrice=0; 

    QSqlQuery myqry;
    myqry.exec("SELECT ItemPrice FROM Item WHERE ItemId='"+itemSelect+"' ");
    if (myqry.next())
        price = myqry.value(0).toDouble();

    totalPrice = price * qtySold.toInt();

    QString totalPriceString = QString::number(totalPrice);

    myqry.prepare("INSERT INTO Sold (ReceiptId, ItemId, SoldQuantity, TotalPrice) VALUES ('"+receiptNo+"', '"+itemSelect+"', '"+qtySold+"', '"+totalPriceString+"') ");
    myqry.exec();

    ui->comboBox_itemID->setCurrentIndex(0);
    ui->lineEdit_qtySold->clear();

    myqry.prepare("SELECT Item.ItemId, Item.ItemName, Item.ItemPrice, Sold.SoldQuantity FROM Item, Sold WHERE Item.ItemId = Sold.ItemId AND Sold.ReceiptId='"+receiptNo+"' ");
    myqry.exec();

    QSqlQueryModel *myModel = new QSqlQueryModel();
    myModel->setQuery(myqry);
    ui->tableView->setModel(myModel);

    double sum = 0;
    myqry.exec("SELECT SUM(TotalPrice) FROM Sold WHERE ReceiptId='"+receiptNo+"' ");
    if (myqry.next())
        sum += myqry.value(0).toDouble();

    ui->label_totalAmount->setText("TOTAL AMOUNT: RM" + QString::number(sum));

    //<--THIS-->//
    myqry.prepare("INSERT INTO Receipt (ReceiptId, ReceiptDate, ReceiptAmount) VALUES ('"+receiptNo+"', '"+currentDate+"', '"+totalAmount+"') ");
    myqry.exec();

}

void CashRegister::on_pushButton_finish_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\joeboy69\Documents\Workshop 1\ASTECHNOWERKZ\cashregister.cpp:100: error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'const QString' and 'QDate')
     myqry.prepare("INSERT INTO Receipt (ReceiptId, ReceiptDate, ReceiptAmount) VALUES ('"+receiptNo+"', '"+currentDate+"', '"+totalAmount+"') ");
                                                                                                           ^
```

Screenshot:

[Screenshot of the Code with Error - View it HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6GFP.jpg)

Comment: Your question doesn't meet the "minimal" or "complete" parts of a [mcve].

Comment: The error message seems pretty self-explanatory.  You cannot concatenate a `QDate` on to a `QString`.  Perhaps just change to:  `QString currentDate = QDate::currentDate().toString("YYYY-MM-dd");`?

Comment: `myqry.exec("SELECT ItemPrice FROM Item WHERE ItemId='"+itemSelect+"' ");` and also things like `myqry.prepare("INSERT INTO Receipt (ReceiptId, ReceiptDate, ReceiptAmount) VALUES ('"+receiptNo+"', '"+currentDate+"', '"+totalAmount+"') ");`. This is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen. See [`QSqlQuery::prepare`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#prepare) on the proper usage.

Comment: @Justin yeah got it, thanks alot. Wil check it then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should convert `QDate` to `QString` using [`toString()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#toString-1).

```
myqry.prepare(
    "INSERT INTO Receipt (ReceiptId, ReceiptDate, ReceiptAmount) "
    "VALUES (:receipt, :date, :amount) ");
query.bindValue(":receipt", receiptNo);
query.bindValue(":date", currentDate.toString());
query.bindValue(":amount", totalAmount);
query.exec();
```

However, if you want things to be simple and don't care of SQL injection attack, you could do it like this. You've been warned:

```
myqry.prepare(
    "INSERT INTO Receipt (ReceiptId, ReceiptDate, ReceiptAmount) "
    "VALUES ('"+receiptNo+"', '"+currentDate.toString()+"', '"+totalAmount+"') ");
```

Also, you may need to adjust the format of the string returned by `toString()`.